# Subviews of UIScrollView stay in same position while UIScrollView scrolls veritcally

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift4

Can anyone tell me why the subviews that I've added to my UIScrollView won't scroll? When I run the project I can scroll the UIScrollView up and down, I can see the scroll-indicator on the right side of the screen as I scroll. But the subviews that I've added to the UIScrollView stay in the same position as if they aren't subviews of the UIScrollView at all. This is very strange because I copied most of this code from another view i'm using and its working exactly as expect, just this view won't work . Thanks for looking, here's my code

```
import UIKit

class EnterCredentialsVC2: UIViewController {

    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = { [unowned self] in
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.ricdBlue
        view.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.size.height + 300
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    private let emailTextField: UITextField = { 
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Email Address"
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return field
    }()

    private let passwordTextField: UITextField = { 
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Password (6 characters minimum)"
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return field
    }()

    private let enterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    private let errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            layoutView()
    }
}


//view layout methods
extension EnterCredentialsVC2 {
    private func layoutView() {
        layoutScrollView()
        layoutEmailTextField()
        layoutPasswordTextField()
        layoutEnterButton()
        layoutErrorLabel()
    }

    private func layoutScrollView() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    private func layoutEmailTextField() {
        scrollView.addSubview(emailTextField)
        emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width * 0.9).isActive = true
        emailTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    private func layoutPasswordTextField() {
        scrollView.addSubview(passwordTextField)
        passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width * 0.9).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    }

    private func layoutEnterButton() {
        scrollView.addSubview(enterButton)
        enterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width * 0.5).isActive = true
        enterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
        enterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        let top = enterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 50)
        top.priority = .defaultHigh
        top.isActive = true
        let bottom = enterButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 200)
        bottom.priority = .defaultLow
        bottom.isActive = true
    }

    private func layoutErrorLabel() {
        scrollView.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width-20).isActive = true
        errorLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        let top = errorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enterButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 30)
        top.priority = .required
        top.isActive = true

        let bottom = errorLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        bottom.priority = .defaultLow
        bottom.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints of direct subviews inside a scroll view work in a special way. They must be pinned either to the scroll view itself or to its `contentLayoutGuide`. This has a special meaning: "I'm not really pinned to your outside, I'm just showing you the layout of the subviews and I'm telling you your content size."

Pinning to the safe area layout guide — a thing that never moves — completely violates that. It's like pinning to the scroll view's `frameLayoutGuide`, or to something outside the scroll view altogether. It specifically instructs the scroll view *not* to take these views into account when working out the content height.

You had explicitly given the scroll view a content size — in a wrong way at a wrong time, but that's a different matter — and "luckily" that caused the scroll view to be scrollable. But if you set up the internal constraints correctly, any explicit setting of the `contentSize` is ignored.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. What would be the right way and the right time to set the scroll view content size?

Comment: If you're using auto layout, never. That's the point; the subviews and their constraints take care of it.

Comment: When I remove the line where I set `contentSize` the scroll view no longer scrolls

Comment: Then you are just guessing the content size instead of letting the subviews dictate it?

Comment: I set it equal to `view.frame.size.height` and it allows for a little bounce

Comment: Ah, so this is not really a scroll view that does any significant scrolling. What happens on a device with a shorter screen?

Comment: I used the scroll view because it adds a nice bounce to the screen and it saves me from having to scrunch the screen together for the iPhone 5 screen (incase anyone still has one) . On the iPhone 5 screen it will scroll down enough to show all the UI elements.

Comment: But again, that's because you are _guessing_ at the total height of the UI elements. It would be better to let the UI elements themselves dictate the height. I understand that your code seems to work, so you are not tempted to make any changes, but I assure you that this is not the right way and bad habits will eventually cause mystifying results.

Comment: Ok i agree but could you tell me what the right way to do it is such that I still get the bounce action form the Scroll view? Currently I'm setting the contentSize.height equal to the the view.frame.size.height. I don't see what's wrong with that? It ensures the scroll views height always matches the height of the view...

Comment: "Currently I'm setting the contentSize.height equal to the the view.frame.size.height. I don't see what's wrong with that? It ensures the scroll views height always matches the height of the view..." No. In `viewDidLoad`, the scroll view's frame is not yet known. You are using the frame of the scroll view as it _was_ in the _storyboard_. But this will not be the actual size on a bigger or small screen than the design size you happened to use in the storyboard. If you try your code on a taller iPhone, or on an iPad, you'll find you have no bounce.

Comment: I have no storyboards i created all the views programatically. The scroll view has a bounce on every iPhone device available in the simulator

Comment: Can you describe the method that you would recommend one uses?

Comment: It isn't what I recommend. It's what you do. You pin the subviews to the scroll view all the way from the top to the bottom. The instrinsic or explicit height constraints of the subviews tell the scroll view its content height.

Comment: Here's a rudimentary example if you've never heard of this feature: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p360scrollViewInCode/ch20p570scrollViewInCode/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of the issue, here is the line that I changed:

```
private func layoutEmailTextField() {
    ...
    emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

constraining the textFields `topAnchor` equal to `scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor` is different than constraining it to the `scrollView.topAnchor`. [Here is the relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) and also [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area). My thoughts are that because the safeArea is any area that is not obscured by the device, the subviews were forced to stay within that area and therefore wouldn't scroll beyond it. Although I'm not sure why they wouldn't bounce around whatsoever, even within the safeArea... anybody who knows more on this please leave a comment, thanks.